# What is the logic of @Rule(JUnit) declaration and assignment in a Groovy class

Tags: java, groovy, junit, junit-rule, junit-runner

Trying some variants of rules creation in a groovy file, I have come to the thought, that @Rule doesn't describe DECLARATION, but ASSIGNMENT.
So, the runner, when loading the test, tries every rule for the correct assignment.

```
//Correct variants:
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector1= new ErrorCollector();

public ErrorCollector collector2= null;
@Rule
collector2= new ErrorCollector();

public ErrorCollector collector3;
@Rule
collector3= new ErrorCollector();


// incorrect variants:
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector4= null;

@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector5;

@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector5=somethingThatIsNotRule;

@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector5=anotherRule;
```

But, then I came to some paradoxial variants:

```
//these lines are not only taken by the runner, but also passed without errors:
public ErrorCollector collector6;
{
  @Rule
  collector6= null;
}

public ErrorCollector collector7=null;
{
  @Rule
  collector7= null;
}
```

What is the logic of it?

It seems as a bug in Runner - the runner makes an excessive check before constructing the test.

Comment: Not possible, if you take a look at `@Rule` annotation, it has targets `FILED`&`METHOD`. Your paradoxial variant should not compile, because essentially it's a field assignment inside instance initializer block, not field declaration.

Comment: well, I can only assume there is a bug in Eclipse compiler. This piece of code does not compile in IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have forgotten to mention that it was all done in groovy file - groovy is not so strict as java - edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the JUnit runner checks that the `@Rule` annotation is applied to a public non-static field or public non-static method which returns either a [TestRule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestRule.java) or [MethodRule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/MethodRule.java).

If there is `@Rule` annotation on a field or method, then the value must be a non-null value or you'll get a NullPointerException during execution of the test.

Your example is more complicated than that because Groovy is a dynamic language, so it does its checking at runtime, not compile time. I suspect that collector2 and collector3 aren't actually doing anything. The `@Rule` annotation doesn't apply to the field.

```
collector4 => NullPointerException
collector5 => same as collector5
collector5a => when you execute, I suspect Groovy doesn't find the
               expected methods on your somethingThatIsNotRule, or
               you're getting a ClassCastException or something similar.
collector5b => same as 5b for anotherRule
```

For your paradoxes, again, the `@Rule` annotation isn't actually applying to the field.

I suspect your confusion comes from the fact that Groovy doesn't complain about the usage of `@Rule` on something that isn't a field or method (whereas Java would). It may not complain, but JUnit will ignore such an annotation.

Comment: I have noticed it already. Yes, for collectors 6 and 7 the collectors in {} are new ones. BTW, in my Groovy code the ErrorCollector works OK on a static field. And yet I'll have one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966146/why-does-errorcollector-demands-for-assignment-at-the-moment-of-declaration. And please, could you check the tag def: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/90826. Thank you.